# Using Jquery to detect ellipsis

Tags: html, jquery, css, ellipsis

I have a long sentence showing ellipsis at the end.

I want to use jquery to detect if ellipsis is there, a popup will show up.

But somehow popup doesn't show when the page loads.

Please give me a hand.

```js
var e = $('.text')[0];

if (e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth) {
    alert("Ellipsis")
}
```

```css
.text {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.width{
 width: 30%
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width">
<div class="text">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (e.innerText.includes('…'))`

Comment: @abcid d I have updated the code in the answer. Try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check each element in turn and set the class.  You also need to account for a screen re-size.  Here I add a resize event handler and then trigger it on startup as well as handle it when the screen re-sizes.

To test this here us the "Full page" on the output window and resize the browser.

```js
function checkEm() {
  $(".text")
    .removeClass('wrapped-el')
    .filter(function() {
      return this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight;
    })
    .addClass('wrapped-el');
}
$(window).on('resize', checkEm).trigger('resize');
```

```css
.text {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.width {
  width: 30vw;
}

.width-m {
  width: 45vw;
}

.width-mw {
  width: 60vw;
}

.width-w {
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapped-el {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="width">
  <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
<div class="width-m">
  <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
<div class="width-mw">
  <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
<div class="width-w">
  <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Schultheiss, Thank you very much for giving me a hand!  Your solution is best suited my case.  Please help me with a little bit further.  I need to add a new class on .text's parent.  When I add `.parent().addClass('wrapped-el');`, it works.  But when I add `$(".text").parent()` to remove `('wrapped-el')`, it doesn't work.  Please take a look at my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3hefwos2/2/

Comment: using jQuery I rarely use .parent() but instead look for an ancestor with a given class using `. closest()` https://api.jquery.com/closest/  this is however a new question and not part of detecting the ellipsis.  I recommend a study of each of the pertinent tree traversal methods and noted here https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Keep in mind that jQuery is "chainable" meaning if you get the `.parent()` in your chain, that is the new chained element i.e. that is the new context of the next method in the chain. Context is important here and once you get the parent you don't then have to "re-get" the parent since you then get the "grandparent" when you do so

Answer (score 1):

Just check the size of the text and the container, text element just trigger a overflow over it's parent, but with ellipsis this is not visible, at least that's a way to understand it

```js
function hasEllipsis(selector) {
    // let $element = document.querySelector(selector); // no jquery version, check the available selectors, it works with class selector ".text"
  let $element = $(selector);
  
  // for document.querySelector dont use index zero
  // $element[0] jquery is the same as $element with queryselector
  return $element[0].offsetHeight < $element[0].scrollHeight;
}

console.log(hasEllipsis(".text"));
```

```css
.text {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.width {
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="width">
  <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to check if text is ellipse or not:-

```js
let parentDiv = document.querySelector('.width');
let textDiv = document.querySelector('.text');
let width = textDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let height = textDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;

let tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
let tempText = document.createTextNode(textDiv.innerText);
tempDiv.className = 'tempdiv';
tempDiv.style.cssText = "opacity: 0; position: fixed; width: " + textDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
tempDiv.appendChild(tempText);
parentDiv.append(tempDiv);

let tempWidth = tempDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let tempHeight = tempDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;

tempDiv.remove();

// Check width and Height
if (width != tempWidth || height != tempHeight) {
  alert("ellipse Found");
}
```

```css
.text {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.width{
 width: 30%
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width">
<div class="text">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That _only_ checks if the property `text-overflow` is set to `ellipsis`- it does _not_ determine whether any text actually gets cut and _shows_ an ellipsis at the end.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, that;s a requirement. And in css this is the way to show ellipse in the text. And you can't do ellipse without text-overflow property. So, by checking this, we actually can determine whether text has ellipsis or not. So, please read the requirement in the question, before commenting

Comment: _"So, by checking this, we actually can determine whether text has ellipsis or not."_ - no, you can't. If you reduce the whole text in your example to just the single word "Lorem", it will _still_ say that the text had an ellipsis.

Comment: @CBroe Listen, if the text has property, only then it will show ellipsis. So, what are you trying to say??? If I reduce the whole text to one word , still for ellipse I have to use text-overflow: ellipse. Then only way is to check that property. Its simple!! It doesn't have any concern wether your text is short or long. We are only checking ellipse. Please read question

Comment: They want to know whether the text _does_ get shown truncated with an ellipses at the end, at whatever the current element width is. Your code _always_ says "ellipsis Found", even if the text is so short (or the element so wide, depends how you want to look at it), that it can be displayed in full, _without_ an ellipses showing.

Comment: @CBroe Oh Oky, I understand what you are saying. I am sorry. And thank you for explaining. Furthermore, I have updated the code, please try now. Is it oky now??

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery, it's a good idea to use its capabilities.
P.S. It is not necessary to specify `text-overflow: ellipsis;` if you use `-webkit-line-clamp`.

```js
if ( $('.text').prop('scrollHeight') > $('.width').height() ) alert('Ellipsis');
```

```css
.text {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.width {
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width">
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad recusandae perspiciatis accusantium quas aut explicabo ab. Doloremque quam eos, alias dolore, iusto pariatur earum, ullam, quidem dolores deleniti perspiciatis omnis.</div>
</div>
```